# Cannot make fixed block visible if height greather than body

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a problem that I can not make navigation block visible if(its fixed)

styles:

```
 <div class="main_nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
                        <h1 class="navbar-brand company_title" href="#">Tourer</h1>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-9">
                    <div class="navigation">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right top_nav">
                            <li><a id="nav_about" href="javascript: void(0);">About</a></li>
                            <li><a id="nav_how_it_works" href="javascript: void(0);">How it works</a></li>
                            <li><a id="nav_features" href="javascript: void(0);">Features</a></li>
                            <li><a id="nav_footer" href="javascript: void(0);">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   .main_nav {
       width: 100%;
       z-index: 1000;
       position: fixed;
       background: url('../images/gradient.png');
       padding-top: 30px;
       min-width: 1280px !important;

   Screen:

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zljz4.png
```

I cannot scroll to see the right part of my nav.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The fixed position is always relative to viewport. Hence, `min-width: 1280px !important;` automatically assumes that your `width:100%` will be ignored when the screen is smaller than 1280px. Try remove the `min-width` declaration.